# Apache giving 503 for SSL request to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, https

I have a Rails 3 app using Ruby 1.9.2 configured to work on the Linux server. The uses SSL to access all there resources. Now, I am dealing with the SSL so that I can display the application on the client side. The user LDAP credentials are being passed to the Linux server through instructions in the httpd.conf file. I can see the
handshake in the SSL_error logs. I also know the cert information is being
passed because I can see the information in the SSL_client logs and also
in the Rails WEBrick server console as my application boots (http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/chris_rohr/configuring_webrick_to_use_ssl.html). However
when I go to the Https port on my desktop I get the browser error "503
Service Temporarily Unavailable". I know the cert was passed to the
browser because I get the "lock" icon.

Can someone help me understand the 503 error?

Comment: Is using Apache or lighttpd with [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) an option?

Comment: You should post the exact, verbose error.

Comment: Tadman and Karudzo thank you for your responses. I found the error had nothing to do with webrick but with the Apache httpd.conf. The proxy port was not setup correctly. As far as using something other than webrick, I am looking at passenger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 503 error like that from your front-end usually means your back-end (Mongrel? Webrick?) is down or misconfigured in terms of ports.